# why solana-test-validator is not working?

Tags: solana

`solana-test-validator` is not working, don't know why it's happening, anyone can help.
I have searched about it but didn't find much help

[Click here to see the error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qpAM.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is tripping on a line that creates a symlink: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b66e2ae3530c02955683da0bc0bf090673f0be16/validator/src/bin/solana-test-validator.rs#L359

On Windows, you need admin or developer privileges to create symlinks: [Why are Administrator privileges required to create a symlink on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991523/why-are-administrator-privileges-required-to-create-a-symlink-on-windows)

Try re-running this from a Bash-supporting shell with admin privileges.